# How do I change the tab stops in a Command Prompt/Console window/DOS Box?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console, dos

I have a .NET console window and some of my columns I'd like to have wider than the tab stop, without doing fancy coding, simulating my own tabs, or using an alternative console or output device.

It ought to be easy! Is there a vt100 command or something I can send? Or is my Google-fu that weak?

thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm currently using stuff like `String.Format("{0,-10}", celldata)` for the problem columsn but there are issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx)?

```
string str;
str = "BBQ and Slaw";

Console.Write("|");
Console.Write(str.PadRight(15));
Console.WriteLine("|");       // Displays "|BBQ and Slaw   |".

Console.Write("|");
Console.Write(str.PadRight(5));
Console.WriteLine("|");       // Displays "|BBQ and Slaw|".
```

Comment: Thanks - I think that's equiv. to the string.format... but if nobody ever tells me how to actually change the tabstops I'll go for it too.